# javaScript: Why does toString() not work directly with a number but with a number variable declared?

Tags: javascript

```js
y = 15;
let x = y.toString(10);
console.log(x)
```

This prints '15' but

```js
let x = 15.toString(10);
console.log(x)
```

gives Error: Invalid or unexpected token
Why?

Comment: The snippet tool's syntax highlighting gets confused for the same reason.

Comment: @James Thorpe I looked for this thoroughly on stack overflow before asking and nothing remotely similar was even among the 10 suggestions when I was typing the title. If this already has an answer, kindly provide the link to the same and I shall willingly delete my question.

Comment: @UpasanaSengupta The link to the other Q&A is at the top of the post in the yellow box - being marked as a duplicate isn't a bad thing - hopefully you still get your answer, and if your question is phrased slightly differently to the other, it will act as a sign post for future searches to hopefully find the answer also.

Answer (score 5):

It works with another dot for separating the property from number.

```js
let x = 15..toString(10);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: You definitely got some nice syntax tricks :)

Comment: Is this because the first point after the number should mean the decimal point?

Comment: right, the dot of a number has a higher precence.